# woocommerce update variation in cart

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I want to show product variations which come through the woo-commerce gravity form add-ons
on the cart page in the table after product name column.

Mean I want to show the product options which can change or update after adding to the cart.
How can I do ?

Please help me out to sholve the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would require some heavy customizations to the templates. Not quite that easy considering you'd also have to use AJAX. If you're looking for a place to start, take a look at editing the templates in `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/cart/` and using template overrides. Not quite an answer here but also not something that can be answered easily.

Answer (score 0):

I my case was a template problem, I fixed this converting my theme in child of twentyxxx theme and adding this code in head section of header.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri()?>/js/prettyPhoto/jquery.prettyPhoto.js?ver=3.1.5'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri()?>/js/prettyPhoto/jquery.prettyPhoto.init.js?ver=2.2.10'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  var wc_single_product_params = {"i18n_required_rating_text":"Please select a rating","review_rating_required":"yes"};
  var wc_single_product_params = {"i18n_required_rating_text":"Please select a rating","review_rating_required":"yes"};
  /* ]]> */
  </script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri()?>/js/frontend/single-product.js?ver=2.2.10'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri()?>/js/jquery-blockui/jquery.blockUI.js?ver=2.60'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  var woocommerce_params = {"ajax_url":"\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","ajax_loader_url":"\/\/ahrf-preview.nettheory.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/woocommerce\/assets\/images\/ajax-loader@2x.gif"};
  var woocommerce_params = {"ajax_url":"\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","ajax_loader_url":"\/\/ahrf-preview.nettheory.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/woocommerce\/assets\/images\/ajax-loader@2x.gif"};
  /* ]]> */
  </script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri()?>/js/frontend/woocommerce.js?ver=2.2.10'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri()?>/js/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js?ver=1.3.1'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  var wc_cart_fragments_params = {"ajax_url":"\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","fragment_name":"wc_fragments"};
  var wc_cart_fragments_params = {"ajax_url":"\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","fragment_name":"wc_fragments"};
  /* ]]> */
  </script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri()?>/js/frontend/cart-fragments.js?ver=2.2.10'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ahrf-preview.nettheory.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js?ver=20141010'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ahrf-preview.nettheory.com/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.js?ver=4.1'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  var screenReaderText = {"expand":"<span class=\"screen-reader-text\">expand child menu<\/span>","collapse":"<span class=\"screen-reader-text\">collapse child menu<\/span>"};
  /* ]]> */
  </script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ahrf-preview.nettheory.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/js/functions.js?ver=20141212'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  var wc_add_to_cart_variation_params = {"i18n_no_matching_variations_text":"Sorry, no products matched your selection. Please choose a different combination.","i18n_unavailable_text":"Sorry, this product is unavailable. Please choose a different combination."};
  /* ]]> */
  </script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri()?>/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.js?ver=2.2.10'></script>
```